# Efficiently finding the next event in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The basic gist of my issue is, for every event A, I need to find the earliest following event B that's associated with the same user. Currently, I have:

```
SELECT e.UserID, e.date, min(e2.date) 
FROM Event e INNER JOIN 
    Event e2 ON e.UserID = e2.UserID AND e.date <= e2.date
WHERE e.Event LIKE 'A' AND e2.Event LIKE 'B'
```

However, for every event A (which can happen for a user any number of times), numerous event B's happen, so the inner join is creating numerous extra rows that it then has to weed through on the min function.  Is there a more efficient/faster way of doing this?

(the server is MSSQL Server 2008)

**UPDATE:**
Would it be faster with Rank()?

```
Select UserID, date, date2 
from (
    Select e.UserID, e.date, e2.date as date2, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY e.date, e.UserID ORDER BY e2.date) as rank
    FROM Event e INNER JOIN Event e2 on e.UserID = e2.UserID
    WHERE e.Event = 'A' and e2.Event = 'B' and e.date <= e2.date
)
WHERE rank = 1
```

Or will optimization bring them out to basically equivalent?

Comment: Using `min` seems fine to me. However is there a reason you're using `LIKE` as opposed to `=`. That's where the real performance drain look to be.

Comment: Don't you need a `GROUP BY` in there?

Comment: Jacob: I'm a little new to SQL, so what happens differently between like and =?

Comment: Tom: You are right, there's a "GROUP BY e.UserID, e.date" in there which I forgot because the whole thing is a bit of a paraphrase of my original anyway :p

Comment: @jodaka `LIKE` is generally used for things such as `e.Event LIKE 'B%'` for all events that start with the letter "B". However, doing those kind of comparisons takes more processing work. @Tom H. yes. He also needs to add `GROUP BY e.UserID, e.date` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it faster to join a third time, like this? Probably not, but it might be worth trying. Here any data returned in table "e3" represent dates **inbetween** the e date and the e2 date. So we left join with that and grab the `NULL` values.

```
SELECT e.UserID, e.date, e2.date 
FROM Event e 
INNER JOIN Event e2 ON (e.UserID = e2.UserID AND e.date <= e2.date)
 LEFT JOIN Event e3 ON (e.UserID = e3.UserID AND e.date <= e3.date AND e3.date <= e2.date AND e3.Event = 'B')
WHERE e.Event = 'A' AND e2.Event = 'B'
AND e3.date IS NULL
```

I am thinking this probably uses the same strategy as your `MIN` query, but maybe not? I'm curious to know either way.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but that seems to work incredibly fast.  I don't have access to IO stats, so I can't say for sure. But I like it.

Comment: If it is too good to be true, make sure it returns the correct data! Another note: notice that `e3.Event = 'C'` is in the `JOIN` condition. If you move that to the `WHERE` clause, you will get incorrect results. If you end up using this answer, you may want to leave a comment to yourself about this -- that if you ever go back and add more conditions on the `e2` table, they also need to be placed on the `e3` table.

Comment: So I ran some tests, and if ASP.NET's StopWatch is reliable (which it probably isn't), this method is the slowest of the three for small data sets (limiting to events in the last month), but the fastest for large data sets (limiting to the last four years).  I guess all the ordering adds up to slow down the rank and min version?

Comment: Are you in a position to `EXPLAIN` the query? It would be interesting to see how the plans are different.

Answer (score 0):

The only faster way of doing this that I know requires you to process each event A in a loop and find the first event B using a separate query that uses TOP and ORDER BY which allows it to look the answer up in a suitable index. This could be done in a stored procedure for maximum efficiency.